# How to change message shown to user when screenshots are disabled via windowmanager in flutter

Tags: android, flutter

I'm currently using the [flutter_windowmanager](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_windowmanager) package to prevent users from taken screenshots or recording videos of my app in Flutter. I simply add the necessary flag on startup and remove it when the app is closed by calling this code:

```
  Future<void> secureScreen() async {
    await FlutterWindowManager.addFlags(FlutterWindowManager.FLAG_SECURE);
  }

  Future<void> removeSecureScreen() async {
    await FlutterWindowManager.clearFlags(FlutterWindowManager.FLAG_SECURE);
  }
```

But I'd also like to change the message shown to the user when they try to take screenshots while they're disabled. Right now it just says `Can't take screenshot due to security policy.` in a popup message. I just want to show the user a different message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this plugin:
https://pub.dev/packages/screenshot_callback

This is their example:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:screenshot_callback/screenshot_callback.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  ScreenshotCallback screenshotCallback;

  String text = "Ready..";

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    init();
  }

  void init() async {
    await initScreenshotCallback();

  }

  //It must be created after permission is granted.
  Future<void> initScreenshotCallback() async {
    screenshotCallback = ScreenshotCallback();

    screenshotCallback.addListener(() {
      setState(() {
        text = "Screenshot callback Fired!";
      });
    });

    screenshotCallback.addListener(() {
      print("We can add multiple listeners ");
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    screenshotCallback.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Detect Screenshot Callback Example'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Text(text,
              style: TextStyle(
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              )),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

You can for example show a `Dialog` or `Snackbar` with a message that says that screenshots can't be taken.

Comment: Tried that library @Andrej. Problem with that is it requires the user to give permissions. Is there any way I can implement it without having to ask user for permission?

Comment: No, you have to ask for a permission. There is no way to do it without a permission. You could however not allow the user to use the app if they don't give you the permission.

Comment: This will not work out for me, unfortunately, but for anyone else that might have a similar problem but don't mind asking the user for permission, this is a good solution. Marking this as the answer.

Comment: It's a shame that it doesn't work for you.